# Worklight - Geo location not working in background in iOS

Tags: ios, geolocation, ibm-mobilefirst

I have implemented the Location services in android and it can continually get the device's position even when the application is in the background. However, when I tried it running in an iOS Simulator and iOS device, the device stops retrieving its location when I place the application in the background. I don't think this should be the behavior. Is there other settings needed to be configured for iOS? thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Start by explaining what you Did configure.

Comment: I haven't configured anything so far. since I just run in my iOS device the same code I used in android.

Comment: The guide specifically mentions to set permissions. Please read the training module.

Comment: Oh. sorry. i missed that. is the info.plist the same as the <projectname><appname>iphone.plist? Based on the training module Geo: UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities: location-services gps (when enableHighAccuracy=true) should be added, however, the plist is in xml form. how do I add these lines?

Comment: You do that in Xcode.

Comment: did you manage to set-up the permissions?

Comment: yes. it's already working. thanks.

Comment: Great. I wrote this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Per the discussion in the comments:*

Make sure to also set the Geolocation permissions in the *-info.plist file in Xcode per the instructions [in the training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/10_04_Location_services_in_worklight_applications.pdf) (slides 21-22) and/or the [user documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/r_wl_location.html).